# Can input variables be separated by a comma?

Tags: python, input

> Write a program that reads a number of feet from the user, followed by a number of inches. Once these values are read, your program should compute and display the equivalent number of centimeters

I wrote the following code:

```
feet = int(input('Enter feet: '))
inches = int(input('Enter inches: '))
centimeters = ((feet * 12) + inches) * 2.54 
print("Height in centimeters: ", centimeters)
```

Can I have the user input both feet and inches on the same line? For example the prompt might look something like this:

```
Enter height ____ , ____
```

Both inputs would be separated by a comma to indicate that the left is feet and the right is inches. Is this possible and would both numbers be able to be stored as different variables as to complete the conversion into centimeters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input()` function along with `split()` method. `input()` function returns the user input as a `string` object. So, you can use `split()` method to split the user input (string) whatever way you want. Example:

```py
ft, inch = input('Enter feet and inches separated by comma(,)').split(',')
```

Above code works with no issues, while the user input have no spaces, example `10,12`. With the approach of using `,` as separator be careful of the input cases like `10, 12`. In this case, there is space before `12`. So, after getting user input as shown above, you can use `strip()` method to get rid of spaces at the beginning or end of a string.

**OR,**

you can ask user to provide input separated by space.

```py
ft, inch = input('Enter feet and inches separated by space').split()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uI=input("Height (ft,in):").split(",")
feet=uI[0]
inches=uI[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new here, but if I remember correctly, you should probably use a split function, ((something that you want to split.split()). So firstly, you could assign feet and inches to 0 as a variable.

```
feet = 0
inches = 0
```

Then, you can ask for the input.

```
feet, inches = (input(Enter height, separated by a comma: )).split(s)
```

At this point you should separate your input, for example, '6, 3'. Python will now assign feet to a new variable(feet = 5), and inches as well (inches = 9). You can now convert this into centimeters, and both numbers will be stored as different variables. Alternatively, if there are multiple inputs you will be having, be sure to include first have:

```
feet = []
inches = []
```

This is so that you can now independently retrieve certain information from the list, perhaps to make a table of converted inputs?

You could also input separately, but as far as I know, including the split in the input is the easiest way to go. Hope this helps :D